# Is the recent achievements on top navigation bar not working?

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

I saw similar issues on meta but they were all 2+ years old.

[image]

This section still shows reputation changes from yesterday and no updates for today. Although the reputation tab in profile is working perfectly.

Comment: @yivi I thought so but those realtime updates via websockets won't show up either 

Comment: It doesn't work for me either..

Comment: I'm not sure if that is cache. The recent inbox and reputation count beside it is working as expected. It's just that 'recent achievements' section.

Comment: same to me... :(

Comment: Related Q on the SE meta: [I'm not getting reputation notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367961/131247)

Comment: Ah I didn't check meta *stackexchange*

Comment: Not been working for me either; got one notification this morning for an upvote, nothing since (and I've had 3 more upvotes and an accepted answer since then).

Comment: It seems it's slowly starting to work. Just received notification for reputation earned like 8-9 hours ago

Comment: Answer on the stack exchange site https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367989/328025